# Visual Studio : Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is my home screen :

[image]

When I hit the `Log On` on the right side , I reach this :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /HelloWorld/LogOn

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

This is the hierarchy of my project in Visual Studio 2012 :

[image]

This is the `_Layout.cshtml` contents :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
              <h1>Welcome to our MVC Movies Application                  
              </h1>             
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                <!-- My TEST Comment -->
                <!--
                    From here we go into to log-on page , furthermore if the user is 
                    not listed , then we go straight into registration
                    -->
              [ <a href="/HelloWorld/LogOn">Log On</a> ] @*This is just a non-working stub that would be changed later on*@
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <!--  format is as follows 
                        [the name of the presented tab] 
                        [the name of the file in the Search Solution]
                        [the folder in Search Solution where the file above is located]
                        -->
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home Tab", "Index", "Movies")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Search Tab", "SearchIndex", "Movies")</li>
                     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Hello World Tab", "Index", "HelloWorld")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the `LogOn.cshtml` contents :

```
@model Mvc3ToolsUpdateWeb_Default.Models.LogOnModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LogOn";
}

<h2>Log On</h2>
<p>
    Please enter your user name and password. @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have an account.
</p>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here ? what causes the 404 ?

I guess that something is wrong with the path in the layout file :

```
<a href="/HelloWorld/LogOn">Log On</a>
```

Much appreciated

**EDIT:**

**HelloWorldController.cs:**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers {
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1) {
            ViewBag.Message = "Hello " + name;
            ViewBag.NumTimes = numTimes;

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `HelloWorldController` with a method named `LogOn`?

Comment: @CodeCaster: I have the controller , but not the method . I edited the code in the post .

Comment: Well since you're calling `/HelloWorld/LogOn`, you must. Are you sure the `LogOn` requires this path, or can you change it to point to the controller that actually contains the `LogOn` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this...

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Hello " + name;
            ViewBag.NumTimes = numTimes;

            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

You need one action do display the login page (if required) and one that takes in the users credentials.

Edit: I have added the default `Login` actions you get with new MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

Use `./HelloWorld` or `../` instead. Many times, a server won't accept `/HelloWorld`

Comment: is this related to `/` being some form of root path?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Visual Studio Development Server. You can right click on your project, under solution name in Solution Explorer. There, you can choose IIS Express.